# Errors with Fallout Shelter time glitch?

Tags: fallout-shelter

There are many videos which explain how to do a time glitch in Fallout Shelter. The problem is, when I do it, my dwellers stop picking up items and my radio station time doesn't reset. How do I make this glitch work right?

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted, it's just there to help.

Comment: You can post a question and an answer separately if you want to help others. Posting both as a question is not how the site works. If you fix this question to *just* be a question and put your answer as an answer to it, it will likely be reopened and the have its downvotes reversed.

Comment: Thank you, sorry, this is my first post. Hope the fix is ok.

Comment: @Ironshot30 yes, much better. I am voting to reopen. You should also post your fix as an answer.

Comment: voted to reopen as well

Answer (score 1):

Many players know of this glitch and have had trouble with trying to get items from sending dwellers into the wilderness, or resetting the radio station timer. I found out how to fix the problem by trial and error, here are the steps:

This for sure works on IOS, but should work for Android (still need confirmation)

1. Open the vault you want to glitch.
2. Switch to settings (without closing Fallout Shelter), then go to General, Date & Time.
3. Switch off "Set Automatically" time.
4. Change the time to 7 days earlier. (So if today was the 10th of January, changed the time to the 3rd of January)
5. Go back to the game, it will seem as if nothing happened. (Nothing should happen yet)
6. After waiting a few seconds, go back to the Date & Time and Switch on "Set Automatically" time. (This will make the game think you jumped ahead 7 days, from the 3rd of January to the 10th).
7. Voila, you got your free Lunchbox, and you can once again get items when you send your dwellers out into the wilderness.

Extra info:
There will be a small loading screen when you go ahead in time but not backward. (From the 10th to the 3 there will be no loading screen in Fallout Shelter, but there will be when you go from the 3rd to the 10th)

Also, if the loading screen isn't moving, give it some time, I have never had trouble with this glitch and the game. If it does take too long, close the game and retry, it should work the second time.

The difference between how most players do that hack and how I do it is that I put the time back 7 days, and then put it back to my original time. Most players set it ahead 7 days, and keep repeating, and then when done, go back that amount of days to their original time. For some reason, the second way of doing it creates bugs in the game and problems, but the way I present is just as simple, and doesn't come with those bugs.

Comment: That way it's worded, this appears to be for iOS.  Does it work for Android too? Or does this glitch only work for the iOS verison?

Comment: Good question, I don't own an android, but it should work the same for both IOS and android, but I would need someone to check that.